# Why is the output of _$ _ when executed on a terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have executed the following command sequence:

```
$ now=$(date)
$ echo _$now_
_
$ echo _ $now _
_ Mon Sep 22 09:53:44 IST 2014 _
```

Why is the output of `_$now_` only `_`?

Answer (score 11):

From [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc7):

```
DEFINITIONS
       The following definitions are used throughout the rest of this document.
       blank  A space or tab.
       word   A sequence of characters considered as a single unit by the shell.
              Also known as a token.
       name   A word consisting only of alphanumeric characters and underscores, 
              and beginning with an alphabetic character or an underscore.  Also 
              referred to as an identifier.
...
PARAMETERS
       A parameter is an entity that stores values.  It can be a name, a number, 
       or one of the special characters listed below under Special Parameters.  
       A variable is a parameter denoted by a name.
```

A variable can only have alphabets, numbers and underscores. And so `now_` is a valid variable name, and is interpreted as such.

You can delimit the variable name in different ways:

```
_"$now"_
_${now}_
_$now"_"
_$now'_'
```

Or any combination of the above.

Answer (score 10):

because `_` is part of the variable name in your `echo _$now_`

use `echo \_$now\_` instead.

Also you can use that just in a linear command: `echo _$(date)_`

Comment: or use braces to separate the variable name from the surrounding text: `echo _${now}_`

Comment: @glennjackman that's covered in [@muru's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/526980/283843). thankx

Answer (score 7):

Bear with me for a moment, this requires a bit of explaining.

First of, why is output of `_ $(date) _` is `_ Mon Sep 22 03:30:34 MDT 2014 _` ? Because this literally tells echo to output _ first then output $(date) then _ . Spaces separate the variables for echo.

Now try `echo _$(date)`, note no space between `_` and `$(date)`. In this case output will be `_Mon Sep 22 03:32:40 MDT 2014` . What does this do? you tell `echo` to concatenate  underscore with output of `$(date)`.

Try same thing with `_$PWD`, which will concatenate your working directory with underscore. Now try `echo $PWD_` . The output will be blank. Why? because `PWD_` is non-existent environment variable, and as others have mentioned `_` is valid character for an environment variable, e.g. `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` .

So why `_$PWD_` would give `_` ? Because you are telling `echo` to concatenate `_` with output of non-existent environment variable. So `_` is printed, but `$PWD_` output is blank, so you literally see `_` concatenated with that blank output.

Comment: Then, why print `_`?

Comment: @ KasiyA I didn't read question first time around properly. See the edited answer

Answer (score 1):

```
_$now_
```

is interpreted as

```
_${now_}
```

which is, in your case, obviously the string concat of '_' and ''. Use therefore

```
_${now}_
```

instead. It is much more clear to read.